# Active Pattern in match clause

Tags: f#

I am trying to better understand how active pattern works - please correct me if i am reading active pattern wrong, taking below example:

```
let (|UpperCase|) (x:string) = x.ToUpper()

let result = match "foo" with
                 | UpperCase "FOO" -> true
                 | _ -> false
```

I see we are comparing

```
(Uppercase "foo") with "FOO"
```

but it looks odd in this case, when i read

```
| UpperCase "Foo"
```

shouldn't this code be written like

```
let result = match UpperCase "foo" with
```

Is there a better way to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you are combining two [patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching): the single case [active recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns) without arguments `UpperCase` with the constant pattern `"FOO"`. The effect is indeed the same as if you were to apply the function `(|UpperCase|)` inside the match expression:

```
match "foo" with
| UpperCase "FOO" -> true
| _ -> false
// val it : bool = true

match (|UpperCase|) "foo" with
| "FOO" -> true
| _ -> false
// val it : bool = true
```

Now, matching constants against constants is not very versatile, so let's  make a function instead.

```
let isFooBarCaseInsensitive = function
| UpperCase "FOO" | UpperCase "BAR" -> true
| _ -> false
// val isFooBarCaseInsensitive : _arg1:string -> bool
isFooBarCaseInsensitive "foo"
// val it : bool = true
isFooBarCaseInsensitive "fred"
// val it : bool = false
```

Patterns are employed not only with the `match` and `function` keywords, but also with `try...with`, `fun`, and most notably `let`:

```
let (UpperCase foo) = "foo"
// val foo : string = "FOO"
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of a match as a simplified if/else chain. For example:

```
match "foo" with
| "foo" -> true    
| _ -> false
```

Could be:

```
if "foo" = "foo" then true
else false
```

Active Patterns are implicit function calls. In your example:

```
match "foo" with
| UpperCase "FOO" -> true
| _ -> false
```

Is essentially:

```
if (UpperCase "foo") = "FOO" then true
else false
```

You're matching the result of pushing "foo" through the call, you just don't have to specify it with the usual function call syntax.

To answer your other question, in this particular case you could very well do this for the same effect:

```
let UpperCase (x:string) = x.ToUpper()

match UpperCase "foo" with
| "FOO" -> true
| _ -> false
```

It becomes a little more difficult to do that when you could have multiple pattern results that you'd like to match against, which is where Active Patterns are more useful.

For example:

```
let (|IsInt|IsString|) (x:obj) = match x with :? int -> IsInt | _ -> IsString

match someValue with
| IsInt -> true
| IsString -> false
```